Someone Help me at Polkadot.js
I have staked dot currencies in this platform for a while and transferred them after release but after a long time no tokens have been deposited into my wallet. Please help me because all my capital was these currencies.
you can see images of transaction to guide me:
Transaction to this wallet pic 
Transaction pic 1
sign the transaction pic 
